# Hooking into mercurial pretxncommit. And can't import requests module?

Tags: python, mercurial, commit, pre-commit-hook

Hi I'm trying to hook into the mercurial pretxncommit python file.
Most of my code works fine but I get this error:

> error: pretxncommit.pcrcheck hook raised an exception: No  module
>   named requests transaction abort! 
>   rollback completed abort: No module named requests!

I'm trying to use `requests.get`. `import requests` works fine in another stand alone python file I made but it seems like hooking it into mercurial is causing a problem where it can't import this module.
Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, so I think I need to find the path to where HG-Tortoise imports it's python packages for mercurial. Seems that HG-Tortoise probably has a path to where it gets it's imports from, and so can't see where I'm importing the Requests module from.

Comment: Looks like the end of this page might have the answer: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.3/faq.html

Comment: your link is now at http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/faq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up having to add all of these lol. You have to add the path to your external packages onto the path that Mercurial is using.(http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/faq.html) And yes it looks like they were all necessary to get the `requests module` working, I kept getting different import errors without them.

Here's what I added:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\\')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-3.1.0-py2.7.egg\\simplejson')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-3.1.0-py2.7.egg\\')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-3.1.0-py2.7.egg\\simplejson\\tests\\')
```

Comment: This is annoying :( but looks like there is no other way!